# the HTML page is not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, loading

When I am running from the cmd its showing that Connected to MongoDB but when I am running in the localhost its showing that CANNOT GET. I dont know why.

```
    var express = require('express'),
    filter = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(filter),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

    server.listen(7550, '127.0.0.1');
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:7550/');

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/filter_CheckBoxSchema', function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log('What happened!!!');
    } else{
        console.log('Connected to mongodb!');
    }
});

var filter_CheckBoxSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    category : { name: String, type: Boolean, default: false },
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var Filter = mongoose.model('Filter', filter_CheckBoxSchema);

filter.post('example.html', function(req, res){
    new Filter({
        name: req.body.name,
        type: req.body.gender,

    }).save(function(err, doc){
        if(err) res.send('Successfully not inserted...');
        else
        res.send('Successfully inserted!!!');
    });
});
```

Please Help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you change the code to if(err) { throw err; }  and give us output of it? That will provide more info on what is wrong

Comment: Same things is happening...I have changed the code to if(err){throw err;} but getting same result.

Comment: Can you connect to and query Mongo directly on the same endpoint as your application is trying to?

Comment: All done.but still facing problem.

Comment: Typically routes begin with a / and do not include a filename like that. At any rate, how are you POSTing data to `/example.html`?